# cant start foreground service from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Im trying to create a chat head like button that will appear when someone calls my phone
i ran up to 2 problems:

1)the Call Receiver will only start when the user starts my app, i understand thats the new regulation  and receivers wont start till the app is running still is there a way to make it start on phone startup?

2)the service its suppose to start on call wont start (it shows in the log that the method is called but the service isnt) i would like to understand why and how to fix it

the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="********"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:name="MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="*******.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- handle incoming calls -->
        <receiver
            android:name="*********.CallReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="*****.FloatingButtonService" />  

    </application>

</manifest>
```

the receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.i("GABI", "CallReciever onRecieve()");
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.v("GABI", "state is:"+state);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
            String num = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.v("GABI", "phone ringing, num:"+num);

                Log.v("GABI", "adding floating button");
                addAppButtonToCallScreen(context);//add out application to the main call screen

        }
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))//call ended or hanged up
        {
            //remove our button from screen
            removeAppButtonFromCallScreen();
        }
    }
/**
     * add our application to the main call screen
     * @param context 
     */
    private void addAppButtonToCallScreen(Context context) 
    {
        Log.i("GABI","addAppButtonToCallScreen()");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FloatingButtonService.class);  
        context.startService(intent);  
    }
```

the service:

```
public class FloatingButtonService extends Service  
{
    private WindowManager _windowManager;  
    private ImageView _floatingButton;
    private boolean _isMove;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {  
        Log.i("GABI", "FloatingButtonService.OnCreate()");
        super.onCreate();  
        _floatingButton = new ImageView(this);  //the logo bubble as imageView  
        _floatingButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_call);   
        _windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE); 

        //set the layout params 
        final LayoutParams myParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(  
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,  
                LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,  
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); 

        myParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;  
        myParams.x=0;  
        myParams.y=100; 


        // add a floatingButton icon in window  
        Log.v("GABI", "adding the view");
        _windowManager.addView(_floatingButton, myParams);  

        try{  
            //for moving the picture on touch and slide  
            _floatingButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
                WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsT = myParams;  
                private int initialX;  
                private int initialY;  
                private float initialTouchX;  
                private float initialTouchY;  
                private long touchStartTime = 0;  

                @Override  
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {  
                    Log.i("GABI", "floating button touch event");
                    //remove button bubble on long press  
                    if(System.currentTimeMillis()-touchStartTime>ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() && initialTouchX== event.getX())
                    {  
                        _windowManager.removeView(_floatingButton);  
                        stopSelf();  
                        return false;  
                    }  

                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {  
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
                        touchStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  
                        initialX = myParams.x;  
                        initialY = myParams.y;  
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();  
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();  
                        break;  
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (_isMove==false)
                        {
                            startApp();//start our application
                        }
                        break;  
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  
                        myParams.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);  
                        myParams.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);  
                        _windowManager.updateViewLayout(v, myParams);
                        _isMove=true;
                        break;
                    }  

                    return false;  
                }

            });  
        } catch (Exception e){  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  

    /**
     * show toast    */
    private void startApp() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pressed button weeeeeeeeee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

and ofcourse the log:

```
01-08 18:03:56.745: I/GABI(10149): CallReciever onRecieve()
01-08 18:03:56.745: V/GABI(10149): state is:RINGING
01-08 18:03:56.745: V/GABI(10149): phone ringing, num:0549968089
01-08 18:03:56.745: V/GABI(10149): adding floating button
01-08 18:03:56.745: I/GABI(10149): addAppButtonToCallScreen()
01-08 18:04:04.645: I/GABI(10149): CallReciever onRecieve()
01-08 18:04:04.645: V/GABI(10149): state is:IDLE
01-08 18:11:45.765: I/GABI(10543): CallReciever onRecieve()
01-08 18:11:45.765: V/GABI(10543): state is:RINGING
01-08 18:11:45.765: V/GABI(10543): phone ringing, num:0549968089
01-08 18:11:45.765: V/GABI(10543): adding floating button
01-08 18:11:45.765: I/GABI(10543): addAppButtonToCallScreen()
01-08 18:11:57.950: I/GABI(10543): CallReciever onRecieve()
01-08 18:11:57.950: V/GABI(10543): state is:OFFHOOK
01-08 18:12:11.275: I/GABI(10543): CallReciever onRecieve()
01-08 18:12:11.275: V/GABI(10543): state is:IDLE
```

Comment: add `@Override` before onCreate of Service

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Updated. It's still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can set a specific receiver to get notified when the phone gets turned on by catching the action **[android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name="com.my.CustomReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

2) Does the chat-heads-like overlay works if started manually? Any Exception?

Comment: the code for the overlay isn't called, i have specific log calls on the service on create even before i do anything yet it isn't displayed in the log, as for the code for the overlay it was taken as is from another tutorial i suppose it doesnt contain errors